# Notify user of progress in SPSS

Tags: scripting, vbscript, spss

I have the below SPSS code in my script;

```
MsgBox "Progressing"
For iCaseCount = 1 To iNumberOfCases
     'my code here
Next
```

I want to remove the MsgBox and place 'it' inside the loop and replace it's content with; "Progressing record: " & " of " & iNumberOfCases

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to show the progress via Internet Explorer.

Below is the VB Script Code.

```
Dim objExplorer
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objExplorer.navigate "about:blank" : objExplorer.Width = 350 : objExplorer.Height = 80 : objExplorer.toolbar = False : objExplorer.menubar = False : objExplorer.statusbar = False : objExplorer.Visible = True

For iCaseCount = 1 To iNumberOfCases
    DisplayProgress(objExplorer, iCaseCount, iNumberOfCases)
    'my code here
Next

objExplorer.Quit
Set objExplorer = Nothing
```

Method to show progress

```
Sub DisplayProgress(ByVal x As Object, ByVal stage As Long, ByVal total As Long)
     'in code, the colon acts as a line feed
     x.Refresh
     x.document.write "<font color=black face=Arial>"
     x.document.write  "Processing record " & stage & " of " & total
     x.document.write "</font>"
End Sub
```